# Choosing Spellchecker language

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify via HTML or Javascript the language that should be used for spellchecking.

I've tried something like

```
<input lang=fr spellcheck="true"/>
```

but the default language is still used.

So is it possible at the moment with javascript/html?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set language on the html-tag. But you have no guarantee that the browser notices that. Directly configuring the spellcheck of the browser is "impossible" <- no standards or plans to define one for that till now.

Comment: I've tried with the lang in the html tag but that doesn't seems to work on most browser.
Pretty sad ...

Comment: I'm afraid that that means you're out of luck. You have to implement your own spellchecker via ajax if you have to provide a configurable one.