# How to I get spellcheck in a specific language for html inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

When I write: "Hei, ejg heetr Ola Nordmann"(Misspelled version of "My name is John Doe in Norwegian"), I want to get suggestions in Norwegian when I right click the misspelled words. E.g "ejg" should give me the suggestion "jeg" and "heetr" should give me the suggestion "heter".

I've tried this:

```html
<textarea lang="no">Hei, ejg heetr Ola Nordmann</textarea>
```

But I always get suggestions in English. Even when I change my browser language. How to I get browsers to give me suggestions in the specified language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing Spellchecker language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215770/choosing-spellchecker-language)

Comment: I suppose it does. Basically means its not possible in a native way:(. Thanks though